# RangeSlider does not work with scatter plot

Tags: bokeh

Is it possible to make the range slider work with a scatter plot? The slider works if I change the scatter to a line plot but that does not work for me as I can not use the box select tool with line plots. The snippet below is simplified to demonstrate the issue. I suspect the embedded JavaScript is the issue but I may be wrong as it works just fine with a line plot. Thanks.

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, RangeSlider, Column, Row
from bokeh.plotting import figure

x = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
y = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
scatter_plot = figure(width=250, plot_height=600)
scatter_plot.scatter(x, y)
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(y_range=scatter_plot.y_range), code="""
var start = cb_obj.value
y_range.start = start[0]
y_range.end = start[1]
""")
depth_slider = RangeSlider(width=250, show_value=False, start=-20, end=120, value=(20, 80), step=20, 
title="Y Scale")
depth_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
layout = Column(Row(depth_slider), scatter_plot, )
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some race condition going on or a discrepancy between how Python and JS version of Bokeh work.
By default, all ranges are instances of `DataRange1d` class which recompute `start` and `end` when needed. In this case, it for some reason recomputes the values after you set them manually.

To fix it, specify the range manually from the get go:

```py
scatter_plot = figure(..., y_range=(20, 80))
```